# What is the bug with arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Strange situation in javascript:

```
var arr1=new Array();
var arr2=new Array();
arr1=[[1,2],[3,4]];
for (i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
 arr2[i]=arr1[i];
}
alert(arr2[1][0]); //-> 3
arr1[1][0]=10;
alert(arr2[1][0]); //-> 10
```

I do not understand why this is happening

Comment: Javascript assign array by reference not by value

Answer (score 7):

You build an array of array in line 3.

Within the for-loop you do **not** clone the inner array, but just copy a pointer to it. Hence, if you later on change the contents of an inner array in `arr1` it also effects `arr2`.

No bug here anywhere.

If you want to clone the inner arrays, use something like this:

```
for (i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
 arr2[i] = arr1[i].slice(0);
}
```

- [MDN reference on Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0):

arr1 and arr2 are each arrays of arrays; hence, arr2 is built up of the same set of arrays as is arr1, so that assigning to an element of arr1[i] 'magically' shows up as the same element of arr2[i].

Comment: @CC: I guess you missed the quotes

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone the array....like this

```
var arr2 = arr1.slice(0);
```

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)